# I have a confusion about creating the user profile when the user is newly registered

Tags: python, django, web

**views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
##            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,'Account created succcessfully')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid information! Please retry!')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'register.html',context)

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('homepage')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'No current user!')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'login.html',context)

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required
def profile(request):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Profile updated successfully!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
##            'user':request.user,
            'u_form':u_form,
            'p_form':p_form,
    }
    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=350,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='default.png',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name.username)+'\'s Profile'
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Profile
        fields = ['mobile', 'address', 'image']
```

**Error msg:**

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /login/
User has no profile.
```

I am facing an issue that the user profile could not get created or updated although I used the signals for the profile model. When I login a registered user, the error message told me that User has no profile. However if I login a user that has created a profile it could show the related information so for newly registered user how to automatically create a profile for that user?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: show your `signup_view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have a existing which does not have any profile because didn't load signal then wile creating that user if it is superuser create the new superuser from terminal delete the existing one who doesn't have profile after login in admin panel by the way i am also using signal for my web here is the code how i use it

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='default.png',)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

tell me if you still got error